# Ubuntu 12.04 I removed an add-in video board and now I can't see anything with on-board video card

Tags: 12.04, video, recovery-mode

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I originally installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a PC with an HDMI add-in video card. I pulled that card and connected directly to the on-board VGA.

When I boot, I see a gray screen, but nothing else. No pointer either.

I'm fairly sure it is booting because I can use left-shift to get to a recovery console. I tried running the following command:

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak`

... but it denied permission.

How do I make this work?

Comment: post the full error report.

Comment: `cannot move \`/etc/X11/xorg.conf' to \`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak': Read-only file system`

Comment: When I run `mount`, I see that /dev/sda1 says `errors=remount-ro`

So I tried running `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sda1` but nothing has improved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remount your `/` partition in read write mode.So try these commands on root shell(recovery mode),

```
mount -o rw,remount /
mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
```

Comment: Thank you, that allowed me to rename the file, but it didn't solve my display problem. There was a change: I now very briefly see the graphical Ubuntu logo, but it disappears after about .5 seconds, then a blank screen.

Comment: You mean black screen.

Comment: At this point, you may be able to get to a login prompt by pressing Ctrl + Alt + F1.